# ê (Unicode character) XML Parsing Error: not well-formed

Tags: xml, utf-8

I have a C++ code with which am creating a SVG document.
I have the character, ê, in a block of text. 
This document gets displayed correctly if I say

xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"

but does not work with encoding="UTF-8" or UTF-16
or default encoding which should also be utf-8.
I tried Firefox, Opera and Rekonq on Ubuntu. Same response by all 3.

I don't understand this because utf-8 is supposed to display ê.
Can anyone explain please?

Comment: Then the document is not *actually encoded in UTF-8*?!

Comment: Yes. I got confused because gvim was displaying the character but the browser was giving me an error. So I didn't realise that the value of the character has to be checked. Am not actually encoding but copying the data from another file so had not noticed that. Thanks for the very nice article link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<xml ... encoding="ISO-8859-1">` just *indicates* what encoding the document is supposedly in. It does not change the encoding of the document. If it works when indicating the document to be in ISO-8859-1, but not with anything else, then that means the document is actually encoded in ISO-8859-1 and not anything else.

If you want a UTF-8 file, you need to actually encode the document in UTF-8 *and* indicate it as such in the `<xml>` declaration.

If you have no idea what that means, see [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).